# .NET Threading - HttpWebRequest BeginGetResponse + AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading

I would like to know which approach among the two is a better implementation ?
I need to create a web request which can range between 200ms to 5 seconds. I need the html response to proceed - so need to block on the main thread.

**First Approach**

```
string GetResponse()
{

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);    

using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result))
{
    using (Stream dataStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

**Second Approach**

```
string response = string.Empty;
AutoResetEvent waitHandle = null;
void GetResponse(string url)
{
    waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(Callback, request);

        waitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        waitHandle.Close();
    }
}

    void Callback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)      
    {           

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
                {
                    if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        using (Stream dataStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                            response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                waitHandle.Set();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you even using the async Begin...method instead of the sync call?  Or is this Silverlight?

Comment: Basically my question should have been is there any advantage in the above approachs in my case ? Would the task be assigned to a IO thread and total execution time reduced ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not execute the web request on the main thread? If you want the main thread to block, this is by far the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: Basically my question should have been is there any advantage in the above approachs in my case ? Would the task be assigned to a IO thread and total execution time reduced ?

Comment: No, this will take longer because you have overhead of managing the other thread. Not a lot longer though, but this really is not going to be faster.