# Trouble with SOAP Request for Quest Diagnostics (using Visual Studio 2010, C#, ASP .NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, soap

I'm new to SOAP here and am trying to make a request to Quest Diagnostics and it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to make the request.

Here's my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Test SOAP Request
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A boolean value indicating whether the function executed successfully or not.</returns>
private bool TestSoap()
{
    // declare necessary objects and variables
    MailMessage mailMsg;
    HttpWebRequest webRequest;
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    ESServiceSoapClient soapClient = new ESServiceSoapClient();
    XmlDocument soapEnvelope = new XmlDocument();
    string soapResult;

    webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://qcs-uat.questdiagnostics.com/services/esservice.asmx");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "https://qcs-uat.questdiagnostics.com/services/esservice.asmx?WSDL");
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";

    soapEnvelope.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:wss=""http://wssim.labone.com/""><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><wss:FullRetrieveCollectionSiteDetails><wss:username>#user name#</wss:username><wss:password># password #</wss:password></wss:FullRetrieveCollectionSiteDetails></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>");

    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        soapEnvelope.Save(stream);
    }

    // attempt async call
    IAsyncResult asyncReslt = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

    // suspend
    asyncReslt.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    // get soap result
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncReslt))
    {
        using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = sReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    mailMsg = new MailMessage("info@evance.com", "rchristiansen@evance.com");
    mailMsg.Subject = "SOAP XML Test Request - Quest Diagnostics";
    mailMsg.Body = soapResult;

    // attempt to send message
    try
    {
        smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.lblError.Text = "Unable to send report email to applicant: " + ex.Message;
        return false;
    }

    // return true - function executed successfully
    return true;
}
```

I removed the user name and the password so you don't try accessing it yourself. Again, I'm new to SOAP and I don't know what exactly is going wrong. Please note that I do have some code that's not used, such as the ESServiceSoapClient. There was a specified method for the function in the object, but that didn't work either (got a EndpointNotFoundException for that).

Comment: I imagine most of this code is from their api. can you post a link to the api page or just clarify if this is the raw api code.

Comment: This is the original SOAP request framework: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wss="http://wssim.labone.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wss:FullRetrieveCollectionSiteDetails>
         <wss:username></wss:username>
         <wss:password></wss:password>
      </wss:FullRetrieveCollectionSiteDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: that is not quite what I meant. I was asking if there is a page like http://help.interfaceware.com/kb/188/3 for this specific operation that you got any amount of this code from?

Comment: I was given a Word Document with the information. And I can't exactly post it here. If you could give me your E-mail address, perhaps I can send it through that way.

Comment: If it was a word document then it is likely under a confidentiality agreement, at least from experience with the PCI, can you just add comments above each line you changed. Should get a good idea from that.

Comment: They only gave me the SOAP XML, which is pretty much what I posted earlier. They didn't give me any documentation in regards to how to code the thing in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this code

```
// get soap result
using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncReslt))
{
    using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        soapResult = sReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

To this:

```
// get soap result
using (WebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncReslt))
{
    using (Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        soapResult = sReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Changes: directly cast the webRequest as a webResponse, Added a line for getResponseStream method

Also is the @ symbol at the begining of the loadXml meant to be there?

References:

[.NET Threading - HttpWebRequest BeginGetResponse + AutoResetEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040510/net-threading-httpwebrequest-begingetresponse-autoresetevent)

[Using the HttpWebRequest class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434703/using-the-httpwebrequest-class)